# Constants as type hints for int bitflag

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have this code:

```py
class Thing():
    FLAG_FOO = 1;
    FLAG_BAR = 2;
    FLAG_JOE = 4;

def call (self, flags: int) -> None:
    ...
```

The method `Thing.call()` should only accept one or a mix of the values that starts with `FLAG_*`, how can I put a type hint for that?

I would like, on VS Code or an IDE that supports type hints, when I write the function it display all the possible values available like so:

```py
t = Thing();
t.call( ... );
        # popup menu that show options:
        # Thing.FLAG_FOO
        # Thing.FLAG_BAR
        # Thing.FLAG_JOE
```

I saw some modules can do that with literal strings but could this work with int bitflags?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntFlag

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks but I don't use a custom class, I need those variables be declared as their own.
Also I tried the enum and it does not show up in the code hints with a popup on vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `enum.IntFlag`:

```
from enum import IntFlag

class Thing(IntFlag):
    FLAG_FOO = 1
    FLAG_BAR = 2
    FLAG_JOE = 4

    def call(self, flags: 'Thing') -> None:
        pass
```

The type annotation specifies that you need to pass a `Thing` (note that for an `Enum` this means one of the class variables that you define as the enumeration; mypy understands how enums work and will error if you try to pass something else as the argument), and when you type `Thing.` you'll see the members in the IDE's autocomplete:

[image: Screenshot of VSCode]

Comment: that's cause a problem on vscode, the object show syntax error when accessing his attributes and also IntFlag extends from int adding all his methods to the class. I think this should not be the way it should be done.

Comment: Yes; you should actually separate this out into two classes instead of having `call` be a method of the class that defines the enum.

Comment: ok, thank you for helping I will go for the way you told me.